# Twilio Audit Tracking?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I have been searching and searching, and my Google skills have failed me.  I was hoping for webhooks from the audit logs, but I found the API endpoints, so I can make calls to gather information.  But what I am missing is: is there a way to track down exactly which API key made the call?

I have been using the API key or secret for authentication and have created a different key for each application.  So I would like to be able to know which key, for example, performed the `phone-number.deleted` event type.

All I see is "User" or "Account," or in the console, just the name of the account.
Why isn't the actor_sid the sk######## value, or the friendly name, or something?

What am I missing?  Otherwise, it seems a little worthless to have keys for segment access, but now you've lost your audit trail.  I don't know now from which site, application, etc. the issue is coming.